# How to resolve error: "Relative import path "$fresh/dev.ts" not prefixed with / or ./ or ../"

Tags: typescript, deno

I have this TypeScript complaint in my editor for a Deno module.

> `Relative import path "$fresh/dev.ts" not prefixed with / or ./ or ../`

There is an `import_map.json` with this content.

```json
{
  "imports": {
    "$fresh/": "https://deno.land/x/fresh@1.1.2/",
    "preact": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.11.0",
    "preact/": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.11.0/",
    "preact-render-to-string": "https://esm.sh/*preact-render-to-string@5.2.4",
    "@preact/signals": "https://esm.sh/*@preact/signals@1.0.3",
    "@preact/signals-core": "https://esm.sh/*@preact/signals-core@1.0.1",
    "twind": "https://esm.sh/twind@0.16.17",
    "twind/": "https://esm.sh/twind@0.16.17/"
  }
}
```

The VSCode TypeScript language server has crashed a couple times, too. I assume it's related.

This code was created by the Deno Fresh project template, and I've not touched it. My understanding is that TypeScript should be cool with these imports, due to the map.

Unless it's not finding the map. Perhaps the spec changed and Deno is out of date. Hmm.

What do you reckon is causing the error?

Looks like [GitHub issue: "Support import maps and bare import specifiers"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43326) isn't done yet for TS:

Perhaps, I should ignore it and not go in these files?

[image: VSCode image of error in editor]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I included the text so it is indexable. The image simply adds. Visuals can be useful when done correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed with a setting in my workspace:

```
  "deno.importMap": "./import_map.json"
```

Comment: I have this same problem, [not on my machine but when deploying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77814003/3416774). This solution doesn't work.

Comment: I never deployed. I actually gave up. Partly because Deno support/uptake seems so lacking compared to OG Node.

Answer (score -3):

If you [change the source directory](https://fresh.deno.dev/docs/examples/changing-the-src-dir), there are a couple things you need to keep in mind:

- Path should not contain a space or a non-ASCII character ([denoland/deploy_feedback issue](https://github.com/denoland/deploy_feedback/issues/590#event-11481105065))
- Import map should be in the source directory for the runtime to work, and on the root for the LSP to work ([denoland/fresh issue](https://github.com/denoland/fresh/issues/2292))