# How to import tailwind plugins in Fresh?

Tags: tailwind-css, deno, typography, freshjs

I'm using Fresh and I want to use two Tailwind plugins: `daisyUI` and `@tailwindcss/typography`. I don't use a separate import map. All are inside `deno.jsonc`. If I just use the `daisyUI` plugin then it works just fine. But I get this error when it's `@tailwindcss/typography`:

`error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Relative import path "typography" not prefixed with / or ./ or ../ and not in import map from "file:///D:/QC%20supplements/Code/Apps/Tr%E1%BA%A5n%20K%E1%BB%B3/Web/tailwind.config.ts"`

I suppose it's because the plugin name contains special characters that makes it hard to do the path correctly, but I don't know how to fix.

Here is my code:

`deno.jsonc`:

```json
"imports": {
    "$fresh/": "https://deno.land/x/fresh@1.6.1/",
    "preact": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.19.2",
    "preact/": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.19.2/",
    "@preact/signals": "https://esm.sh/*@preact/signals@1.2.1",
    "@preact/signals-core": "https://esm.sh/*@preact/signals-core@1.5.0",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:tailwindcss@3.3.5",
    "tailwindcss/": "npm:/tailwindcss@3.3.5/",
    "tailwindcss/plugin": "npm:/tailwindcss@3.3.5/plugin.js",
    "typography": "npm:@tailwindcss/typography",
    "daisyui": "npm:daisyui@4.4.19",
    "$std/": "https://deno.land/std@0.212.0/",
    "deno.importMap": "./import_map.json"
}
```

`tailwind.config.js`:

```js
import { type Config } from "tailwindcss";
import typography from "typography" 
import daisyui from "daisyui";
export default {
  content: [
    "{routes,islands,components}/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
  ],
  plugins: [typography, daisyui],
  daisyui: {
    themes: ["light", "dark", "lemonade", "autumn", "aqua", "nord" ],
    logs: false
  },
} satisfies Config
```

Where do I get wrong?

Related articles:

- [Migrating to Tailwind | Fresh docs](https://fresh.deno.dev/docs/examples/migrating-to-tailwind)
- [Layout and Typography — Tailwind CSS Components ( version 4 update is here )](https://daisyui.com/docs/layout-and-typography/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe in my eyes. I make a test repo, and see that it still works. I suspect it's because of my folder structure because the fresh code in in the `Web` folder, not in the root. I then add the import map:

```
"typography": "npm:@tailwindcss/typography",
```

to `Web/deno.json`, not `./deno.json` and it imports sucessfully!

It seems like a bug to me. See also this related bug: [How to resolve error: "Relative import path "$fresh/dev.ts" not prefixed with / or ./ or ../"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74748570/3416774)

Comment: Turns out this is a bug of a larger problem: [When changing the source directory, import maps needs to be in the source for the runtime to work](https://github.com/denoland/fresh/issues/2292 "When changing the source directory, import maps needs to be in the source for the runtime to work · Issue #2292 · denoland/fresh")